# Can't boot, stuck on grub rescue with no modules?

Tags: boot, grub2, modules

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my new computer (I have already installed it on my old computer, and everything is fine). For some reason, grub said it was not installed. Upon reboot, I reach the grub rescue screen with no bootable device. I tried using normal.mod, but I have no modules. I can't access my bios, and I basically cannot even boot to reinstall. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Try this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/337257/169736) from step 2 onwards

Answer (score 0):

likely some of your files are corrupted during the installation (for me it was root.disk corruption). This is likely to happen if manually reboot during update/install, or other sorts of reason. Another possibility is your CD is damaged.

If you don't have other os installed, I think the only option is to burn another ubuntu install CD(using a working PC, apparently) and boot from it.

Joseph