# Problems uninstalling Ubuntu, trying to put XP back on

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, uninstall, grubrescue

I have an Acer Aspire One ZG5 netbook that came with Windows XP. It was loaned to someone, who then put Ubuntu on it. I know nothing about Ubuntu, so I looked for information on this site for help. It walked me through the steps to uninstall Ubuntu using the Terminal. Now the netbook boots to:

```
Error: unknown filesystem, Grub rescue>
```

I've tried changing the BIOS and then booting with an XP CD but I keep getting a "Stop Error".

I don't have an Ubuntu Live CD.  When I type `ls`, it shows the following:

```
hd0 hd0,msdos5 hd0,msdos1
```

Is the Ubuntu system gone now?

Comment: Or check [how to boot from a CD using grub rescue>](http://askubuntu.com/a/337257/169736) @EliahKagan I think he deleted his Ubuntu partition along his `/boot`, and WinXP recovery methods sucks hard.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can fix your **Grub Menu** in case Ubuntu or **MBR** in case Windows without using a `Bootable CD/DVD` or `Bootable USB`.

- Check this link if you want to fix using Ubuntu LiveCD/DVD: [How to fix Grub Using Ubuntu Live CD/DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
- Check this link if you want to fix using Windows Bootable-CD/DVD:  [How to fix MBR Using Windows Recovery CD/DVD](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/repairmbr.htm)

Boot from Windows, Then if you want to completely remove **Ubuntu** you have to delete partition in which **Ubuntu** is installed, in case it was installed in different partition. Or uninstall Using **Wubi**.

Hope you can understand with this very short description. Reply for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

To get your WIndows XP back, you would need to boot from a Windows XP installation disk, or Windows XP Repair Disk, and would have to do startup repair.

*No operating system can be uninstalled from within itself*.
So after you get your Windows xp back, you would need to delete the partitions that contained Ubuntu.

For help with that, first repair your Windows Xp, then only its possible to remove Ubuntu.